# populate data variable outside for use outside function call

Tags: node.js

I have the next code, for obtain a certain data using pg-client:

```
exports.load_data_view = function (pg, pg_config, param, callback) {
    pg.connect(pg_config, function (err, pgClient, pgDone) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.end(500);
        }

        var query = 'some query...';
        data = [];

        pgClient.query(query, function (err, result) {
            pgClient.end();

            if (err) {
                callback(err, null);
                return;
            }

            data1 = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < result.fields.length; i++) {
                data1.push(result.fields[i]["name"]);
            }
            data.push(data1);

            callback(null, data);

        });
    }
)
}
```

When I need use the data, I do this:

```
for(somecolecction)
{
    data=[]

    exports.load_data_view(pg, pg_config, param, function (err, data) {
        console.log(data); //data is populated
    });


//DoSomethingWith data
    console.log(data) // data is empty


}
```

The problem is: inside the call, `data` contain all that  I need, in the block "DoSomethingWith data", `data` has lost all its values. I have understood that pgClient is async, but, this way to use should not solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

The code is asynchronous and so the second console.log is called before the first one.

So if you want to do something with the data do it in the callback function where your first console.log is.